# Boolean not being returned?

Tags: java

New Developer here, I am doing a practice challenge that should return either true or false depending on if a dog is barking and what time it is in the day.

```
public class BarkingDog {
public static boolean bark(boolean barking, int hourOfDay){
    if(barking=true) {
        if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22) {
            return true;
        } else if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
            return false;
        }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    bark(true,1);
}
}
```

Comment: you need to print it if you are expecting output on your console.

Comment: @James, Welcome to SO. If function would not returned anything, java will not compile it successfully. What is meant by not returning. I see you are not using the  returned result of the function. Maybe printing the value will help you to see the value.

Comment: Firstly, your barking will always be true as you have used assignment operator will make baking variable true instead of comparison(use == instead of =). Secondly if you want to print the value to console. Use System.out.print(bark(true,1));

Comment: Welcome to SO.
Generally I don't think this place is meant for teaching basic java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try it now..
the first thing that was wrong is the IF statement..
 since you should use == not = alone in it.
secondly you should print the answer just to know what really happened.

```
public class BarkingDog {
public static boolean bark(boolean barking, int hourOfDay){
if(barking==true) {
    if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22) {
        return true;
    } else if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
else{
        return false;
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(bark(true,1));
}
}
```

Comment: If you are referring to the last curly bracket, its already in there, whenever i pasted my code into stack it cut it out and put it as paragraph text below my code.

Comment: no actually i wasn't referring to that, its ok i edited the question too

Comment: the reason for not getting result, is method invocation is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: yes that's why i added the printing statement, to show the result. another thing was the == sign which made it not work.

Comment: `barking=true` will just return true and it will not affect the method from returning a value, is not logically correct though.

Comment: of course it won't, but i think @JamesKehs meant to use it as a == not a = sign, to check it not assign it to true, that's why i corrected it too, although it's not the reason for what he asked for.

Answer (score 0):

another small hint: instead of `if(barking=true)` you can just write `if(barking)`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BarkingDog {
public static boolean bark(boolean barking, int hourOfDay){
    if(barking==true) {
        if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22) {
            return true;
        } else if (hourOfDay < 0 || hourOfDay > 23) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else{
            return false;
        }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(bark(true,1));
}
}
```

You are using '=' to check the condition but it use to assign the value.example

```
int a = 1;
```

Use '==' to check the condition.

Answer (score 0):

> when i run it i don't get anything in return.

Because, if a method has a return type(it is returning a value), try to hold this value in same type as the return type in a variable, if you don't assign method invocation to a variable it will be ignored.

```
boolean result = bark(true, 1);

System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can and you should simplify this code.there is nonsense if condition...write code like this :

```
public static boolean bark(boolean barking, int hourOfDay){
if(barking) {
    if (hourOfDay < 8 || hourOfDay > 22) {
        return true;
     else {
        return false;
    }
}
else{
        return false;
    }
}
public static void main(String args[]){
  //this is static values and you can get this values dynamic i.e from server
  boolean result = bark(true, 1);
  System.out.println(result);

}
}
```